# in hadoop,will files copied to master nodes or slave nodes

Tags: hadoop

Shall we copyFromlocal/put file to hdfs before processing map-reduce job? When I run mapreduce example I was taught to format hdfs in master node and copyFromLocal files to that hdfs space in master.

Then why some tutorials said master nodes just inform metadata to client.The laptop(client) will copy file blocks to data nodes not to master? e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziqx2hJY8Hg at 25:50. My understanding based on this tutorial is that the file (splitted by blocks) will be copied to slave nodes. so we do not need to copyFromlocal /put files to master nodes. I was so confused. Can anybody explain where will files copied/replicated to?

Answer (score 0):

Blocks will not be copied to master node.
The master (Namenode) sends meta data to the client containing the data node locations 
for placing each block by the client.
No actual block data is transferred to the NameNode.

I found this [comic](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/edit?usp=drive_web&urp=http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apa&pli=1) to be a good hdfs explanation

Comment: to vijairam and user2876895: if you check this ppt http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminwootton/configuring-your-first-hadoop-cluster-on-ec2: start from page 24, it said formats hdfs at master and then some hdfs spaced is created at /tmp/hadoop-ubuntu at master. 
And then in page 37, before mapreducing, it said put a text file to this hdfs we then see this file is successfully copied by checking hadoop dfs -ls at master. so my understanding is that the file is copied to name node.

Answer (score 0):

The master node (Namenode) in hadoop just deals with the Metadata (Datanode<->data information). It does not deal with the actual files. The actual files are instead stored only in the datanodes.